# Enable virtual host name without a2ensite

Tags: apache2, php

I have a server on DigitalOcean managed by ServerPilot, basically I am trying to add couple static sites without using their panel, to keep them simple possible and no PHP installing required.

I added the configuration for the custom site in `vhosts.d`, and the tutorials say I have to `sudo a2ensite site.com.conf`, but ServerPilot already has `apache-sp` and `a2ensite` says I have to `apt install apache` to use this component..

Any ideas how to add the new name without installing another `apache` package? I am afraid it will mess up the server installing this one.

Best

Comment: You need to refer to ServerPilot documentation then - it looks like they roll a custom Apache instance and their documentation is what you need to look at.

Comment: ServerPilot should have documentation to cover that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that ServerPilot is using their own custom bundle of Apache based on the information you have provided.

A quick Google for ServerPilot and customizing configuration leads me to [this page](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/customize-apache-settings.html) for customizing Apache settings.  This is probably what you need to follow, but you need to be following ServerPilot's documentation either way.

> ### App (Virtual Host) Customizations
>
> #### Adding App Configurations
>
> The easiest way to customize an app's Apache configuration is to add new files in the directory:
>
> ```
> /etc/apache-sp/vhosts.d/APPNAME.d
> ```
>
> Note that Apache loads configuration files from the above directory in alphabetical order.

Comment: TYVM Thomas! I've been to that page but so blind to notice you can set custom configurations in `/etc/apache-sp/vhosts.d/`. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the static sites as separate .conf 's in /etc/apache2/sites-available, then perform a2ensite with the file name as the parameter, then service apache2 reload.

Comment: Thanks Briggy but the thing is the sites are managed by a custom apache service named `apache-sp` by `serverpilot` so there won't be any `/etc/apache2/sites-available` or `a2ensite`..